Best and fastest way to count number of intersection points of line and boundary region in 2d
r1=x^2+y^2==25...
I can use Reduce to find intersection points: Reduce[r1&&x==2,{x,y}] gives the points of intersection, but how to count them?

Length@{Reduce[r1 && x == 2, {x, y}] // ToRules}


Using Solve or RegionMeasure (or RegionMeasure[#,0]&)

r1 = x^2 + y^2 == 25;
sol = Reduce[r1 && x == 2, {x, y}];

Solve[sol, {x, y}] // Length
ImplicitRegion[sol, {x, y}] // RegionMeasure


2


2

